# Google Street View zoom to Fov

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I need to save Street view image exactly as user selected (including panoID, heading, pitch and fov). I have the following code:

```
            panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));
            panorama.addListener('pano_changed', function () {
                $('#panoID').val(panorama.getPano());
            });
            panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function () {
                $('#heading').val(panorama.getPov().heading);
                $('#pitch').val(panorama.getPov().pitch);
                $('#fov').val(panorama.getZoom());
            });
```

problem is I want to save zoom as fov value 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro (look at fov optional parameter)

> fov (default is 90) determines the horizontal field of view of the image. The field of view is expressed in degrees, with a maximum allowed value of 120. When dealing with a fixed-size viewport, as with a Street View image of a set size, field of view in essence represents zoom, with smaller numbers indicating a higher level of zoom.

I found some "convertation" information 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#TilingPanoramas

[image]

but it tells, that fov can be till 180, but prev. link tells 120 value is maximum. Why? 
Of course, I can find ratio for convertation, but maybe exists normal way (i.e. panorama returns Fov instead of zoom)?

Also, seems, catch zoom in pov_changed is not the best way. Sometimes zoom is not updated properly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the following function to convert from zoom to FOV:

```
var k = Math.pow(0.5051, zoom);
var fov = 103.7587 * k;
```

it works (almost exactly) :)

**ADDED**

more precise results:

```
var fov = 180 / Math.pow(2,zoom)
```

thanks to trungk18

Comment: Is this the right way. I saw var fov = 180 / Math.pow(2,zoom) give me more precise results?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula to convert fov to zoom:

- **fov** to **zoom**:

  `zoom = Math.log(180/`**`fov`**`)/(Math.log(2))`

Or vice versa:

- **zoom** to **fov**:

  `fov = 180 / Math.pow(2,` **`zoom`**`)`

<sub>[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319897/4227998)</sub>